# Openssl 3.0 "EVP_PKEY_ASSIGN" is deprecated

Tags: openssl

Let's say I have a function :

```
int test(RSA* rsa){

/* Create a public key */
EVP_PKEY* pubKey = EVP_PKEY_new();

/* Assign the rsa to the public key */
EVP_PKEY_assign(pubKey, EVP_PKEY_RSA , rsa);  /* Deprecated */


}
```

`Openssl` says that `EVP_PKEY_assign` is `deprecated`, what can I use instead of this ?

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

The `_assign` variant was internal and has never even been documented, only the per-type variants `_assign_RSA _assign_DH` etc. For *those* **the man page** on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA.html) says

> EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(), EVP_PKEY_assign_DSA(), EVP_PKEY_assign_DH(), EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(), EVP_PKEY_assign_POLY1305() and EVP_PKEY_assign_SIPHASH() set the referenced key to key however these use the supplied key internally and so key will be freed when the parent pkey is freed. These macros are deprecated. Applications should instead read an EVP_PKEY directly using the OSSL_DECODER APIs (see OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey(3)), or construct an EVP_PKEY from data using EVP_PKEY_fromdata(3).

(except I didn't recreate the hyperlinks -- use the man page to get them).