# C++ How to create EVP_PKEY based on private key with openSSL 3.1 and up

Tags: c++, openssl

How can I create an EVP_PKEY base on private key I provide in openSSL 3.1? I want to use it for to sign in function: EVP_DigestSignInit?

The old way to assign a privat key, created by function PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey, by using EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA is deprecated and cannot find any substiution for it.

I cannot find propare subsitution for these deprecated functions.

Comment: Did you search before asking your question? This is the first hit for me: [Openssl 3.0 "EVP_PKEY_ASSIGN" is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73193265/openssl-3-0-evp-pkey-assign-is-deprecated)

Comment: Yes I have seen it but there is no answer except refers to man pages which is no help.

Comment: Reading the documentation and understanding it is part of programming. But again, if you cannot do that, the next best thing is searching for "OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey example". Which gives a usable example as the first hit.